# Unable to find Private keys (.PFX) for CSR in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, certificate, azure

I am new to CSR and certification creation. My client asked me for a CSR file for creating a SSL certificate. I used DigiCertUtil.exe on my Windows 7 PC for generating the certificate. After two days my client sent me a certificate.

Now, I need to use this certificate on a Web App hosted on Azure. When I try to upload the certificate, Azure is asking for .PFX file and certificate password. It seems that .PFX file has the private keys. I also understood from reading the internet that private keys are stored in the same machine on which the CSR file is created. As per the information on the internet, I went to MMC->certificates->Certificate Enrollment requests, but there is nothing displayed in the panel. I need to understand how I can generate .PFX file and what is certificate password?. I also do not know where should I look for the certificate. (Please note that I am posting this thread after going through various similar questions on superuser. But I didn't get a proper answer)

Answer (score 1):

First, import the received certificate to Windows (into the "Personal" folder), and it will be automatically associated with the private key which DigiCertUtil generated earlier.

Once imported, when you open `certmgr.msc` you should find the certificate under "Personal", and its properties window should say " Private key available".

Then *export* it again, and you will have the option of exporting "with private key" in PKCS#12 format, and this will create a .pfx file containing everything.

You can choose any password when exporting; it is used to encrypt the .pfx file's contents, so the same password needs to be provided when Azure imports the .pfx, and is not needed afterwards.

Comment: I tried these steps, but the PKCS#12 option is greyed out. Also, I have observed that the team who sent me the Certificate has also given me one PCKS#7 Certificate file along with the CSR file. What do I do now?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer by reading the following web site. Basically, I had to import the .CER file using DigiCert utility first to install the certificate and then export it to PFX file. I think, since I used DigiCert utility to create the CSR file, only DigiCert is able to import the file and export it to .PFX file. If this is not the case, then I am not sure why I was not able to do the same from the 'Certificate Manager' in Windows 7.

https://www.digicert.com/csr-creation-ssl-installation-windows-azure-website.htm#azure_ssl_certificate_install_digicert_utility

Answer (score 0):

1. I used the DigiCertUtil.exe for creating CSR for godaddy on my local machine.
2. After domain verification go daddy provided the .crt file as certificate ( download as other type)
3. For windows Azure I needed .pfx file
4. Open the DigiCertUtil.exe - Ensure SSL section is selected and Click on import.
5. Provide the path .crt given by the godaddy
6. Give friendly name "My cert" and Click finish. Now utility shows my certificate.
7. Select the certificate - and click on Export certificate. Provide the password. .pfx file is created
8. Log in to Azure Panel - Select the App - Select SSL setting
9. Clcik on Private Certificate Tab (.pfx) & Upload the certificate
10. Click on Binding TAB - Add SSL binding and link the domain with the certificate.

Answer (score 0):

When I attempted to export the pfx file from the certificate imported into the Microsoft Management Console (MMC) the option to export the pfx file was grayed out (disabled).

You need to have both the private key (.pem file) and the certificate (.spc) on that machine and the Certificate Signing request (CSR) must be done from that machine.

In my case the private key (.pem) was not associated with the certificate (.spc) imported into MMC.  You can tell from the MMC if the private key is missing because the icon for the Certificate will not have the key overlay on top of it.  I followed the Microsoft directions found in the article "Assign a private key to a new certificate after deleting the original certificate in IIS". Basically, I had to get the Certificates serial number and then run this command

C:\Users\me>certutil -repairstore my "your actual serial number"

After this I was able to export the pfx file needed to code sign installers.  The GoDaddy instruction worked after making this fix.